# android Writing to internal storage is not supported

Tags: android

I am try to take photo in private folder and save to public media store.

```
   val takePictureContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { success ->
        if (success) {
            uri?.let { fileUri  ->
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "pic_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
                    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                }
                val mediaUri = contentResolver.insert(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    contentValues
                )
                mediaUri?.let { mUri ->
                    contentResolver.openOutputStream(mUri)?.use { os ->
                        contentResolver.openInputStream(fileUri)?.use { inputStream ->
                            inputStream.copyTo(os)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fun takePic() {
        val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val folder = File(filesDir, "images")
        val file = File(folder, "pic_${currentTimeMillis}")
        folder.mkdirs()
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${packageName}.provider", file)
        takePictureContract.launch(uri)
    }
```

But after take photo, I have this error message. What's wrong with my code?

Error message I get is :

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Writing to internal storage is not supported

---

If change `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, and require permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, I can save photo success.

Comment: You want to save the photo in private folder or public folder?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that has anything to do with taking a photo. And that input stream suddenly is there and you dont tell where it is from.

Comment: @SamChen I want to save the photo to public media store

Comment: @blackapps I edit my code

Comment: Indeed INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI is useless. Not supported . Further i see nothing with taking a photo. And further there is no file you can copy as if you use mkdirs to create a directory then how can it contain a file already?

Comment: @blackapps Thanks to your reply. In fact , if I change to EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, then I can success save photo, I do not know why INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI not work

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @confusedstudent， sorry, not found yet